# Outlook seems to be running but it doesn't open, I can't see it.

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Outlook 2010 seems to be running in the background, but I can't see it or open it.  How can I fix this with out uninstalling and reinstalling Office?

Comment: Is the outlook icon visible in the taskbar? If yes, it may simply be moved out of your display canvas, try moving it with Win+Arrow Keys.

Comment: Yes.  That was it.  Thanks.  I was over thinking the issue.

Comment: Glad you could sort it out that fast. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Outlook runs but main window won't open

This worked for me

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CdFtBIp80FM

The steps that resolved the issue for me are as follows:

1. Right click on the shortcut you use to launch Outlook 2010 and choose Properties.
2. On the shortcut tab next to Run, change it from Normal window, to Maximized.
3. Click OK.
4. Launch Outlook normally using the shortcut you just edited. (If you edited the Start menu shortcut use ONLY it).
   In my case Outlook launched fine, but maximized. Clicking the Restore button would send it irretrievably back to the Taskbar forcing me to force close.
5. With Outlook open and Maximized, right click in the Taskbar and choose Cascade Windows. Presto!
   Now I could minimize, restore, maximize, restore all day long without trouble.
6. Final step is to right click on the previously edited Shortcut and change Run back to "Normal window".

Comment: The above also works for Outlook 2013. The Win+Arrow keys did not.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Outlook only. When I start outlook, the splash screen will appear on my second (Right) monitor and then it disappears. I could make it appear by clicking on the Outlook icon in taskbar couple of times. In my case, problem was that task bar was set to automatically hide. When Outlook is not visible and if I unselect 'Automatically hide taskbar' option, Outlook window appears instantly. I am running Windows 11.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different cause for the same problem, but since Google leads here, maybe this hint will help someone too.

If Outlook doesn't appear in the taskbar even though it is open, but it appears in the notification area, this setting might be responsible:

[image: Hide When Minimized setting]